# Wordpress custom url

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

Есть линка вида `example.com/brand/viking-appliance-repair/?state=CO&city=Denver&zip=90007`, все прекрасно работает, но мне нужен такой вид url: `example.com/brand/viking-appliance-repair/CO/Denver/90007`.

P.S вместо brand может быть appliance, а в место viking-appliance-repair любое другое название.

Пробовал варианты только `example.com/brand/viking-appliance-repair/state/CO/city/denver/zip/90007` - но увы, мне такое не подходит.

Comment: В чем проблема конкретно? Вы не можете в wp сформировать такой url `example.com/brand/viking-appliance-repair/CO/Denver/90007` или при обращении по такому url у вас не открывается страница `example.com/brand/viking-appliance-repair/?state=CO&city=Denver&zip=90007`? Или еще что-то? **Сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен с первого прочтения.**

Comment: уточнил и обновил вопрос